# Get values from Json code

Tags: php, json, api

This is my Json code

```
[
{"ProspectID":"87f3278e-c9ee-4775-abc6-4813969d45a5",
"FirstName":"erter",
"LastName":"nurtertel",
"EmailAddress":"null",
"Company":"null",
"Phone":"null",
"Mobile":"456456456",
"Total":"690"},

{"ProspectID":"00969dcd-5c03-450e-832c-063e976285d5",
"FirstName":"rter",
"LastName":"erte",
"EmailAddress":"null",
"Company":"null",
"Phone":"56456456",
"Mobile":"null",
"Total":"690"}
]
```

In this code i need to get that prospectID.how to get that prospectID in array php code?

Comment: thousands on answers in SO just search

Comment: Did you even searched on net before asking this ques here? You'll get n no. of results for that

Comment: `"LastName":nurtertel` is `nurtertel` a variable or an error? Also, look at [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to change your json string.

put `" "` around null.

use following code to fetch value of `'ProspectID'`

```
$json = '[{"ProspectID":"87f3278e-c9ee-4775-abc6-4813969d45a5","FirstName":"erter","LastName":"nurtertel","EmailAddress":"null","Company":"null","Phone":"null","Mobile":"456456456","Total":"690"},{"ProspectID":"00969dcd-5c03-450e-832c-063e976285d5","FirstName":"rter","LastName":"erte","EmailAddress":"null","Company":"null","Phone":"56456456","Mobile":"null","Total":"690"}]';
$data = json_decode($json);
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++ ){
$ProspectID =   $data[$i]->{'ProspectID'};
echo $ProspectID."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `"null"` is not the same as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is an array, `{}` is a Javascript object.

If you're getting this into a variable, say jsonData, from an Ajax call, your library should parse that string, transforming it into Javascript arrays and objects.
Check your library documentation, you'll probably had to specify the format of the response ('json').

Done this, you'll simply access prospectID.how as below:

```
var jsonData = your parsed string;
alert('ProspectID of first item is: ' + jsonData[0].ProspectID);
alert('ProspectID of second item is: ' + jsonData[0].ProspectID);
```

Obviously, you can also iterate the array with a for..loop